# Likelyhood of a PC having .net 2.0 framework installed

Tags: .net

What is the likelyhood of a PC having the .net 2.0 framework installed nowadays .. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any actual penetration numbers released by Microsoft but Alexander McCabe has [published some information](http://www.centralquestion.com/archives/2009/10/net_penetration_by_version.html) from his web logs which has .NET 2.0 at 70%.

Comment: StatOwl shows NET 2.0 penetration at 83% as of December 2009 and climbing at approximately 1% per month.  See my answer below for the link.

Answer (score 5):

See this blog post:

- [How Many PC's in the World have the .NET framework installed?](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowManyPCsInTheWorldHaveTheNETFrameworkInstalled.aspx)

> After some digging, here's what I've got:
>
> - Well over 90% of the PCs in the world have some version of the .NET
>     Framework installed.
> - Over 65% of Windows PCs in the world have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed.

Comment: This doesn't precisely answer the question.

Comment: @SLaks: ... doesn't precisely answer the question? How do you answer a question like that precisely? This is pretty much as precise as you can get :p

Comment: @Svish: It doesn't address .Net **2.0**.

Comment: @Slaks: that's the best number I can find - I don't know of any more specific or more accurate numbers on .NET 2.0 and up - sorry.

Comment: @Slkas, if 65% have 3.5, then at least 65% have 2.0, since 3.0 and 3.5 are merely extensions of the 2.0 runtime. Therefore, it's a pretty precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what PCs you're sampling. As others have already said, any reasonably up-to-date and service-packed PC should have it installed -- but there are plenty of corporate desktop builds that don't include it, and lots of PCs out there that never get updated.

Answer (score 0):

pretty high if a new pc vista comes with .net framework 3.0 which includes .net framework 2

Answer (score 0):

If the PC runs Windows Vista or higher, it *will* be installed.  (Vista includes .Net 3.0)

If the PC runs XP, it'll probably still be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008 and (I think) Windows XP SP3 all have the .Net framework installed by default.

Comment: Windows XP does not include .Net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to ask? You can ship .Net 2.0 with your app which adds 20MB to the installer. If the client value your program then they should have no problem run your setup program and install .Net 2.0.

I have only client out of thousands of clients that refuse to install .Net 2.0 in their network because the client's network have a software that is somehow incompatible with .Net 2.0 and obviously the client value the software more than ours. We end up back-porting our code back to .Net 1.1 and the client has no problem with losing features.

Comment: 20MB is a *whopping* addition when your program is only a few hundred kilobytes.

Comment: agreed "20MB is a whopping addition when your program is only a few hundred kilobytes" :)

Answer (score 0):

The [StatOwl NET Framework Page](http://www.statowl.com/microsoft_dotnet.php) shows a NET 2.0 penetration of 83% as of December 2009 and trending upward at approximately 1% per month.